# Need to delete objects: implement Dispose or create objects in a function?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, idisposable

I have some objects that read a file, save the data in arrays and make some operations. The sequence is Create object A, operate with object A. Create object B, operate with object B...
The data read by each object may be around 10 MB. So the best option would be to delete each object after operate with each one. Let say I want my program to allocate around 10 MB in memory, not 10MB * 1000 objects = 1GB

The objects are something like:

```
class MyClass
{  
    List<string[]> data;

    public MyClass(string datafile)
    {
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(datafile), true))
        {
            data = csv.ToList<string[]>();
        }
    }

    public List<string> Operate()
    {
    ...
    }

}
```

My question is: should I implement dispose? And do something like:

```
List<string> results = new List<results>();

using (MyClass m = new MyClass("fileM.txt"))
            {
                results.AddRange(m.Operate());
            }

using (MyClass d = new MyClass("fileD.txt"))
            {
                results.AddRange(d.Operate());
            }

...
```

I´ve read that implementing Disposable is recommended when you use unmmanaged resources (sockets, streams, ...), but in my class I have only big data arrays.

Another way would be to create functions for each objects (I suppose GC will delete a object created in a function automatically):

```
List<string> results = new List<results>();
results.AddRange(myFunction("fileM.txt"));
results.AddRange(myFunction("fileD.txt"));


public List<string> myFunction(string file)
{
MyClass c = new MyClass(file);
return results.AddRange(c.Operate());
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IDisposable` etc will not help you here, since it doesn't cause anything to get collected. In this type of scenario, maybe the best approach is to use a *pool* to reduce allocations - essentially becoming your own memory manager. For example, if your `List<string>` is big, you can avoid a lot of the arrays by re-using the lists - after clearing them, obviously. If you call `.Clear()`, the backing array is not reset - it just sets a logical marker to consider it as empty. In your specific case, a lot of your objects are going to be the individual `string`s; that is trickier, but at least they are small and should be collectable in generation-zero.

Comment: If you want to resize the backing array you can set `Capacity = someValue` after calling `Clear()`. (Note that it won't allow you to reduce `Capacity` below the current size so you must clear it first.)

Comment: Reuse a list is a good idea, although in my case is complicated. I read data from some csv files. For each csv, I extract columns of data (a list of string for each column) and create some graphs. Reusing a list for the data read for each csv is easy to implement. But resuing the lists for the columns of each csv is more complicated. One csv may have 3 columns (3 lists), antoher 8 columns (8 lists), so I had to create as many lists as the maximun number of columns a csv may have. And then reause each list for each column.. a complex code. It´d be easier to delete each object with its colums :)

Answer (score 3):

In your case I'd allocate a single buffer array. For example, allocate a 10 MB array once and fill it with the data you want. Then, when you get to the next object, just reuse the array. If you ever need a bigger array, you can just allocate a new, bigger, array and use that instead. The garbage collector will eventually remove your smaller one.

You can also use a `List<T>`, it will internally do the same (allocate an array, keep it until it becomes too small, allocate a new one). Just `Clear` it before creating the next object.

Note that you *cannot force*<sup>1</sup> the garbage collector to collect an object. `IDisposable` is indeed only used to clean up unmanaged resources, as the garbage collector does not know about them, or to close (file) handles. Calling `Dispose` does not guarantee (or imply) that the object is removed from memory.

However, if you change nothing, your code will still be correct and work properly. The garbage collector is responsible for removing unused objects whenever it feels like doing that, and it will ensure that there is plenty of memory available at all times. The only thing you have to do to let the collector do its work is to let go of any references to old objects (by overwriting them or setting them to `null`, or letting them go out of scope).

<sup>1</sup>) You can force the garbage collector to collect your data by calling [`GC.Collect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx). However, this is *not* recommended. Let the garbage collector figure it out by itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4.0 or greater, have a look at the [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) class.  The [constructor that takes the Int32 parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267301.aspx) allows you to specify an upper bound on the size of the collection.  The [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287137.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287085.aspx) methods work as throttles.  Add will only succeed if the upper bound has not been reached.  If it has, it'll block.  Take will only succeed if an item exists.  If no item exists, it'll block until one is available.  Of course, the class has some variations of these methods, so fully examine the documentation to see which, if any, make sense.